# css float left gap issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am using css float left to automatically align but if last element is slightly bigger it goes to next line and makes big gap which looks odd. in mobile devices i want to display only one element per line and it does but again keeps lot of spaces. can i use device width as width ???? for mobile 
is there any better way to do so that it looks like pinterest
direct link 
   here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/hk80gj1m/1/

http://way2enjoy.com/celebrity-wallpapers

```
 <div class="content_main_div div_100_per"><div id="timeline_content"><div><div class="content_box_main">
<div id="5"  align="left" class="messagelove_box" style="width: 225px; float:left; height:310px;" ><div class="content_box_1">
         <div class="content_box_2z"><sup class="joke_icon"></sup></div>
         <div class="content_box_3_title">deepika padukone best hd        <br>16 Wallpapers</div>
         <div class="content_box_3_text"><a href="http://way2enjoy.com/deepika-padukone-best-hd-wallpapers-images-photos-pics" target="_blank"><img src="http://way2enjoy.com/themes/blue/thumbnail.php?file=http://way2enjoy.com/c/deepika-padukone-best-hd-wallpapers-images-photos-pics/Deepika-Padukone-best-hd-wallpapers.jpg&width=180&height=220" alt="deepika-padukone-best-hd-wallpapers-images-photos-pics" title="deepika-padukone-best-hd-wallpapers-images-photos-pics"/></a></div></div></div><div id="4"  align="left" class="messagelove_box" style="width: 225px; float:left; height:310px;" ><div class="content_box_1">
         <div class="content_box_2z"><sup class="joke_icon"></sup></div>
         <div class="content_box_3_title">cute britney spears        <br>18 Wallpapers</div>
         <div class="content_box_3_text"><a href="http://way2enjoy.com/cute-britney-spears-wallpapers-images-photos-pics" target="_blank"><img src="http://way2enjoy.com/themes/blue/thumbnail.php?file=http://way2enjoy.com/c/cute-britney-spears-wallpapers-images-photos-pics/britney-spears.jpeg&width=180&height=220" alt="cute-britney-spears-wallpapers-images-photos-pics" title="cute-britney-spears-wallpapers-images-photos-pics"/></a></div></div></div><div id="3"  align="left" class="messagelove_box" style="width: 225px; float:left; height:310px;" ><div class="content_box_1">
         <div class="content_box_2z"><sup class="joke_icon"></sup></div>
         <div class="content_box_3_title">amitabh bachchan        <br>22 Wallpapers</div>
         <div class="content_box_3_text"><a href="http://way2enjoy.com/amitabh-bachchan-wallpapers-images-photos-pics" target="_blank"><img src="http://way2enjoy.com/themes/blue/thumbnail.php?file=http://way2enjoy.com/c/amitabh-bachchan-wallpapers-images-photos-pics/deewar.jpg&width=180&height=220" alt="amitabh-bachchan-wallpapers-images-photos-pics" title="amitabh-bachchan-wallpapers-images-photos-pics"/></a></div></div></div><div id="2"  align="left" class="messagelove_box" style="width: 225px; float:left; height:310px;" ><div class="content_box_1">
         <div class="content_box_2z"><sup class="joke_icon"></sup></div>
         <div class="content_box_3_title">aamir khan        <br>21 Wallpapers</div>
         <div class="content_box_3_text"><a href="http://way2enjoy.com/aamir-khan-wallpapers-images-photos-pics" target="_blank"><img src="http://way2enjoy.com/themes/blue/thumbnail.php?file=http://way2enjoy.com/c/aamir-khan-wallpapers-images-photos-pics/30548-aamir-1448536297-421-640x480.jpg&width=180&height=220" alt="aamir-khan-wallpapers-images-photos-pics" title="aamir-khan-wallpapers-images-photos-pics"/></a></div></div></div><div id="lastlove_loader"></div>
```

Comment: post html and css in a fiddle.

Comment: @Dejan.S thanks for your comment. by mistake code was not formatted and it was displaying output instead of html. thx.added fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CSS grid, which allows you to create columns. There are a [ton of options](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css%20grid) for grids out there. You can also use the [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) layout mode which is awesome. If you need a more easily applicable tool, you can use a javascript library such as [this](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [this](http://unitegallery.net/).

Comment: thanks for your info. they are awesome. i cant use unitgallery as ads display is problem in that. otherwise its wow type.